# ngx-modals catch event when modals is closed?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-modals and I am adding one boolean into it when modals open I set it to "true" and I want it to "false" when the modals close. No matter I am using Escape key, Click X button or clicking Backdrop to close modals. How to make it possible?

```
openFoodDetail(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
 this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
  template,
  Object.assign({}, { class: 'modal-lg modal-dialog-centered' },)
 );
 this.modalsState = true;
}
```

Can I catch or make the event when my modals is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onHide event in template.

please, see below link :

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-events